# Inline styling on Rails form produces empty string

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am developing a rails application that have a form with post action. I wanted to add inline styling to one of the text box. I used the following code

```
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :name, :class => "control-label"%>
      <div class="controls"><%= f.text_field :name,:class=>'form-control',:style=>"width:initilal;" %></div>
    </div>
```

but surprisingly, when the the page is rendered, the generated HTML for the relevant section becomes:

```
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :name, :class => "control-label"%>
      <div class="controls"><%= f.text_field :name,:class=>'form-control',:style=>"width:initilal;" %></div>
    </div>
```

There is a 'style' attribute in the output but its value is empty.

Why is this happeing?

Note: Using external CSS is not a preferred solution. I am using rails 3.1.1

Comment: i don't think the value you are providing for width is a valid value. what does `width:initilal` mean? try giving something like `width: 10px`

Comment: Your 2nd code block looks the same as your first one. So not very helpful :).